# import mp3 file in CRA / TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have a simple app built in CRA `v3.2.0`. I use TypeScript with the default settings (see `tsconfig.ts` below). In `/src/sounds/` I have a mp3 file "click_hi.mp3" that I want to use in a component, but I can't import the mp3 with the error `Cannot find module 'sounds/click_hi.mp3'.ts(2307)`.

I tried putting the file in the same folder as the component to be sure to avoid typos in the path. But no luck... How can I import the mp3 file?

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Sampler } from "tone";
import ClickHi from 'sounds/click_hi.mp3'


export default function ExercisePage() {
  const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const sampler = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    sampler.current = new Sampler(
      { "A1": ClickHi },
      {
        onload: () => {
          setLoaded(true);
        }
      }
    ).toMaster();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => sampler.current.triggerAttack("A1");

  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={!isLoaded} onClick={handleClick}>
        start
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**tsconfig.ts**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: have you tried [web pack file loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)

Comment: `var ClickHi = require('file-loader!./sounds/click_hi.mp3');` may be this could help.

Comment: What would "importing" an mp3 file look like? Are you looking for the raw data?

Answer (score 5):

For anybody still having this issue, and just like me, does not want to place the assets in the public folder, do it like this, using "**defaul**t":

```
const path = require('../assets/audio/some_audio.mp3');
setAudio(new Audio(path.default));
```

Note: I only have had this problem using TypeScript. You need to declare a module for mp3, by adding to your project src folder a file named something like "audio.d.ts" and content like `declare module '.*mp3';`

Example of simple app working, using this: https://geocarlos.github.io/leiamos/

Comment: This doesn't work with create-react-app. Still gives me the same error. Anything else I need to do?

Comment: I have it working just like this with create-react-app, with TypeScript. But you also need to set a module declaration for mp3. This is where I have it: https://github.com/geocarlos/leiamos.

Comment: And this is where I have declared the module for mp3: https://github.com/geocarlos/leiamos/blob/master/custom-types/audio.d.ts

Comment: Aha! Thank you! I fixed it by now, just by putting the mp3 files into the public folder. Are there any disadvantages to that approach?

Comment: To me, personally, it is just a matter of organization. During development, I like to have assets in the src folder.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by placing the audio file in the `public` folder and referencing it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    sampler.current = new Sampler(
      { A1: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/audio/click_hi.mp3`},
      () => {
          setLoaded(true);
      }
    ).toMaster();
  }, []);
```